# React navigation throwing error when moving between screens

Tags: react-native-navigation

I have defined two screens in my App.js.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import FAQScreen from './FAQScreen';
 
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
 
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="FAQ" component={FAQScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

In my HomeScreen.js I want to simply press a button and navigate to FAQScreen.
However, I keep getting an error:
**The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":FAQScreen}" was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'FAQScreen'?**

I tried to do multiple Google search and found no solution to solve this.

Here is my HomeScreen.js for completeness.

```
mport 'react-native-gesture-handler';
 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView, View, Button} from 'react-native';


class MyButtonText extends Component {
    render() {
  
      var phoneHeight = 500;
      const myFontSize = phoneHeight/25;
  
      return (
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Courier New", fontSize: myFontSize }} onPress = {() => console.log("text clicked")}>
            {this.props.children}
          </Text>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class MyInfoText extends Component {
    render() {
  
      var phoneHeight = 500;
      const myFontSize = phoneHeight/30;
  
      return (
          <Text  numberOfLines = {2} style={{ fontFamily: "Courier New", fontSize: myFontSize, alignItems: "center", textAlign: "center"}}>
            {this.props.children}
          </Text>
      );
    }
  }
  
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    const toolKaiserID = "alkjakljf";

    navigateToScreen=()=>{
        console.log('Going to FAQ screen now...');
        navigation.navigate('FAQScreen')
     
    }

    return (
      // this is a comment
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        {/* top bar */}
        <View style = {topBarStyle.container}>
          <Button onPress={this.navigateToScreen} title="Information" />
          <MyButtonText>ID: {toolKaiserID}</MyButtonText>
          <Button title="Feedback"/>
        </View> 
        {/* info bar */}
        <View style = {infoBarStyle.container}>
          <MyInfoText>paper on floor -- tool(s) on top; take photos from at least 3ft/1m away</MyInfoText>
        </View>
        {/* camera view */}
        <View style = {cameraStyle.container}></View>
        {/* bottom bar */}
        <View style = {bottomBarStyle.container}>
          <Button title="1 Photos"/>
          <Button title="2 Check"/>
          <Button title="3 Editor"/>
          <Button title="4 Paper"/>
        </View>
        
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#434343',
    },
  });
  
  const viewStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
  });
  
  const topBarStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
  });
  
  const infoBarStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
  });
  const cameraStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 5,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  });
  const bottomBarStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },
  });
  

  export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no FAQScreen name in your stack navigator

```
<Stack.Screen name="FAQ" component={FAQScreen} />
```

When you use navigate, it's need the name, that is "FAQ"

If you want to navigate using name "FAQScreen", you can set like this:

```
<Stack.Screen name="FAQScreen" component={FAQScreen} />
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark solved for the answer